# String splitting within a list

Tags: python

I'm supposed to create a function called `lastfirst()` that takes this input:
`['Gerber, Len', 'Fox, Kate', 'Dunn, Bob']`

Then the function should return a list containing two lists of first names and last names, like this:
`[['Len', 'Kate', 'Bob'],['Gerber', 'Fox', 'Dunn']]`

I'm not sure why this is causing me so many problems and I've tried so many different ways of figuring it out, but I just can't get it. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Post your attempts

Comment: How does a question with no attempt shown get three upvotes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sometimes weird things happen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first split & strip items to get name/first name couples, then recombine to get proper arrangement, using listcomps

```
l = ['Gerber, Len', 'Fox, Kate', 'Dunn, Bob']
c = [[y.strip() for y in x.split(",")] for x in l]
result = [[n[1] for n in c],[n[0] for n in c]]
```

result:

```
[['Len', 'Kate', 'Bob'], ['Gerber', 'Fox', 'Dunn']]
```

EDIT: we don't even need the `strip` part if it's guaranteed that the separation is `", "`, because `split` accepts a multichar string argument. In that case it's even simpler:

```
l = ['Gerber, Len', 'Fox, Kate', 'Dunn, Bob']
c = [x.split(", ") for x in l]
result = [[n[1] for n in c],[n[0] for n in c]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of `zip`

```
>>> a = ['Gerber, Len', 'Fox, Kate', 'Dunn, Bob']
>>> b = [i.split(', ') for i in a]
 list(zip(*b))
[('Gerber', 'Fox', 'Dunn'), ('Len', 'Kate', 'Bob')]
```

This returns a list of tuples, but if you truly want a list you can use `map`

```
>>> list(map(list, (zip(*b))))
[['Gerber', 'Fox', 'Dunn'], ['Len', ' Kate', 'Bob']]
```

if you want to reverse the list just used the inbuilt `reversed` function

Comment: you don't handle the leading spaces. But nice. do it using `i.split(', ')`

Comment: oh! that can be fixed with `split(', ')` instead of `split(',')`...fixed

Comment: upvote ... fixed. oh you will have to `reverse` your list too.

Answer (score 1):

Taking Jean-Francois's proposal one step further (BTW, he was right by not giving this answer)

1. Flip name and surname in first step

`c = [[y.strip() for y in x.split(",")][::-1] for x in l]`

The result is

```
In [14]: c
Out[14]: [['Len', 'Gerber'], ['Kate', 'Fox'], ['Bob', 'Dunn']]
```

2. Re-arrange lists - asterick "unpacks" *c* as 3 consecutive lists of *[name, surname]* , and *zip* reshuffles 3 lists of length 2 into 2 lists of length 3

`result = zip(*c)`

This is more advanced approach that you may find useful in the future

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
people = ["Gerber, Len", "Fox, Kate", "Dunn, Bob", "Walsh, Jack"]

def lastfirst(the_list):
    name = []
    lastname = []
    for i in the_list:
        lastname.append(i.split(",")[0])
        name.append(i.split(", ")[1])
    firstlast = [name, lastname]    
    print (firstlast)
lastfirst(people)
```

Made a few corrections, this route is longer but maybe more beginner friendly, at least I would find it so. I realize the output depends on the input being given in correct form as was observed.

Comment: Printing the last line gives me `[' Len', ' Kate', ' Bob'] ['Gerber', 'Fox', 'Dunn']`, not quite what was requested--check the leading spaces.

Comment: I've added another name & last name and it worked fine. Or did you only want the result I get?

Comment: Oh I see now, a list containing two lists.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me when I changed the print statement to this:

Comment: print([name, lastname])

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and take advantage of list comprehension!

```
def lastfirst(l):
    return [[x.split(',')[1].strip() for x in l],  [x.split(',')[0].strip() for x in l]]

print lastfirst(['Gerber, Len', 'Fox, Kate', 'Dunn, Bob'])
```

It will print

```
[['Len', 'Kate', 'Bob'], ['Gerber', 'Fox', 'Dunn']]
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What do you mean ?

Comment: you edited your post _after_ my comment. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

In Repl

```
>>> l = ['Gerber, Len', 'Fox, Kate', 'Dunn, Bob']
>>> print [[x.split(',')[1].strip() for x in l],  [x.split(',')[0].strip() for x in l]]
[['Len', 'Kate', 'Bob'], ['Gerber', 'Fox', 'Dunn']]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
input = ['Gerber, Len', 'Fox, Kate', 'Dunn, Bob']
firsts = []
lasts = []
for i in input:
    s = i.split(',')
    firsts.append(s[0].strip(' '))
    lasts.append(s[1].strip(' '))

result = [lasts,firsts]
print result
```

result:-

```
[['Len', 'Kate', 'Bob'],['Gerber', 'Fox', 'Dunn']]
```

Comment: err, `fists` or `firsts`? and the output is `[['Gerber, Len', 'Dunn, Bob'], ['Fox, Kate']]`, not what the OP expects... I suspect this has never run on your computer.

Comment: @RoryDaulton : now try

Comment: but the input is not the one the OP posted.